# Vagrant ansible provisioning not working

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have a vagrantfile and am trying to instantiate a final provisioner of type ansible where I intend to do the bulk of the work configuring the vm.

The Vagrantfile works fine without the ansible provisioner

```
$vagrant up, destroy, reload etc
```

The Ansible playbook works fine when run directly via ansible

```
$sudo su -i -u ansible ansible-playbook zsh.yml -i hosts
```

But when I try to call

```
$vagrant provision --provision-with install_zsh node2
```

the playbook :

```
---
- name: Ansible TEST Playbook
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Install ZSH
      ansible.builtin.dnf:
        name: 'zsh'
        state: present
```

via this provisioner :

```
node.vm.provision "install_zsh", type: "ansible", run: "always" do |zsh|
  zsh.playbook = "zsh.yml"
end # node.vm.provision
```

Other 'shell' provisioners work fine.

I get this result :

```
==> node2: Running provisioner: install_zsh (ansible)...
Windows is not officially supported for the Ansible Control Machine.
Please check https://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements
Vagrant gathered an unknown Ansible version:


and falls back on the compatibility mode '1.8'.

Alternatively, the compatibility mode can be specified in your Vagrantfile:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#compatibility_mode
    node2: Running ansible-playbook...
The Ansible software could not be found! Please verify
that Ansible is correctly installed on your host system.

If you haven't installed Ansible yet, please install Ansible
on your host system. Vagrant can't do this for you in a safe and
automated way.
Please check https://docs.ansible.com for more information.

$vagrant --version 
Vagrant 2.3.4

$ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.3]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/<username>/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/<username>/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.13 (main, Nov 16 2022, 15:11:16) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-15.0.1)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

I think the first step is in figuring out why my vagrant cannot find ansible

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Used ansible_local provisioner instead

My provisioners look like this now
    
    node.vm.provision "update", type: "ansible_local", run: "never" do |update|
        update.playbook = "/ansible/update.yml"
        update.verbose = false
        update.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
      end

I run a series of Ansible jobs sequentially from this Vagrantfile which works well enough for my needs - feel free to take a look  
[My Vagrant Stuff][1]
Welcome any contributions to improve

  [1]: https://github.com/pauliopolis/vagrant